# Can you get a page access token for a page you do not own, ie you are a third party ? (FB insights)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

Would like to use these FB Graph API insights endpoints for the Nike FB page. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/insights

But, every time I go to the developers.facebook.com tools and generate a new "Page Access Token" and then try to type in the endpoint, I get this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#190) This method must be called with a Page Access Token",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 190,
    "fbtrace_id": "CWg3K5qBxk+"
  }
}
```

Comment: No you can not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page Tokens are for Page owners only. Think about it this way: Would you be able to get access to Google Analytics of some website you do not own? Of course there is also no way to access the Facebook Insights of a Facebook Page you do not own.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you cant get access to info insights.

However you can get some info from the API

For instance:

'Nike?fields=fan_count,pharma_safety_info,phone,description'

returns:

{
  "fan_count": 32788277,
  "description": "Just Do It. ",
  "id": "15087023444"
}